# FIX protocol - handling of SOH presence in String fields

Tags: fix-protocol

I faced the question of handling SOH presence as a value in string fields (for e.g. Account, Symbol and other IDs) used as the delimiter in FIX messages.

Does anybody know how to handle better such cases?

On artio-based FIX server mostly I'm getting Session reject:

`"SessionRejectReason": "5", //  Value is incorrect (out of range) for this tag "Text": "Message parse error"`

Comment: The short of it, you can't directly. Unless you replace all SOH characters with something else (e.g. NUL), and on the receiving end replace them back to SOH. Why would you want to have SOH in String fields anyway? I can't see any reason to do that.

Comment: SOH is only allowed in data fields. Data fields need to be prefixed with a length field so the parser knows how much to parse, not looking for a SOH field.

Comment: Do you have a counterparty that's actually sending SOH in string fields?  If yes, can you give a name so we can all point and shame them?

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier No, I just writing tests, just wanted to get clear expected behavior in such cases.  Basically, the engine didn't go mad, so the test was passed. I found that spec has such reason: SessionRejectReason - 17 = Non "Data" value includes field delimiter (<SOH> character),

Comment: @TT. It's just for tests :)